# coda sliders not working in framesets and frames in IE

Tags: coda-slider

I am using coda sliders in which there are a few images stacked over each other and on mouse click the front most image goes back and the remaining advance forward..
now the problem is it works fine in IE when used individually in a page..
but when it is used inside an frame it is not working...
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

if you use external content in the frame it may result in an display error under IE try to save the content on your site.

If that don`t help take an  instant of an .

Cheers,
Stefan